# Regex to extract address street from completed Address

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract (address street) from the complete Address. I tried a couple of Regex but it doesn't work for all the Address formats.

I tried with this Regex pattern : (^[0-9]+[\sA-Za-z0-9]+)

```
pattern1 = r"(^[0-9]+[\sA-Za-z0-9]+)"
addressRegex = re.compile(pattern1)
text = "9207 ASTORIA BLVD, East Elmhurst, NY 11369"
match = addressRegex.search(text)
match.group(0)
>>> 9207 ASTORIA BLVD
```

but this failing in some cases, can have look at this [regex_tester](https://regex101.com/r/WpRew5/1)

Below are the samples Address in my documents. I've highlighted the Address street part present in the whole address.

**9207 ASTORIA BLVD**, East Elmhurst, NY 11369

**601 B SURF AVE APT 13N** BROOKLYN NY 11224

**2241 WESTERN AVE.** NORCO CA 92860

**89 MILFORD ST** BUFFALO NY 14220

**5550 SPRING VALLEY RD. G-25.** DALLAS. TX 75254

**865 Branford Lane NW** Lilburn, GA 30047

**273-A MONMOUTH STREET,** JERSEY CITY, NJ 07302

**1501 OCEAN AVENUE, UNIT 2605**, ASBURY PARK, NJ 07712

**879 TOMPKINS AVE** STATEN ISLAND NY 10305

**601 B SURF AVE** BROOKLYN NY 11224

**3301 NORTH 88TH STREET** MILWAUKEE WI 53222

**2012 RICHVIEW RD** MOUNT VERNON IL 62864

Comment: tell what is the street no in above mention details. give one example

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the below can capture the **street** part of your address. You can try capture your alternatives into an alternation:

```
^.*?\b(?:BLVD|AVE(?:NUE)?|ST(?:REET)?|R(?:OA)?D|LANE)\b
```

Expand these alternations if need be, see the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJy9Ce/1).

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `.*?` - Lazy match of any character other than newline upto;
- `\b` - Word-boundary.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:
  `BLVD|AVE(?:NUE)?|ST(?:REET)?|R(?:OA)?D|LANE` - All currently given alternatives of streetname endings.

  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `\b` - Word-boundary.

Comment: @RevolverRakk. Please do notice that it does not match the trailing "UNIT 2605" or "G-25" and "13N". Maybe you can take another optional non-capture group holding some alternatives but I do know too little about these type of addrresses to come up with these alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first number that comes in the address is street no, below code extract first no from the string. I am sending you an example

```
str = "601 B SURF AVE APT 13N BROOKLYN NY 11224"
import regex as re
addressNo = []
addressNo.append(re.search(r'\d+', str).group())
```

You can extract all street numbers using a loop.

Comment: hello Talha, thanks for the reply but in the above text "601 B SURF AVE APT 13N" is the address street. I've highlighted the address street part and shared a regex_tester link where I've tested my regex.